# Какой подход используется при зуминге в D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Сабж. На сколько я понимаю зум можно организовать 3 способами:

- transform: scale()
- css-zoom
- И ручное пересчитывание точек на графике

Что используется в D3?
Спасибо!

Comment: css-свойство `zoom` некроссбраузерно, так что не годится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В d3 предлагается использовать `transform: scale()`

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
...

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
    .call(zoom);
...
function zoomed() {
    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate +")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Полный [пример](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708).